# Webcomic about Small Town Horror

Tags: story-identification, horror, webcomics

I lost the link of a webcomic I very recently read and loved, and it’s driving me crazy. It’s a mainly black and white strip, graphic novel style, and heavy with gore and horror elements.

Synopsis: Teenagers are driving into a forest to find a cabin and take wrong turns. They meet some girls standing in a field, who turn out to be extremely fast and strong demon-like creatures, who just look like (hot) young women. Only much later in the storyline are they revealed to be “the wolves”. The wolves kill a lot of the teenagers and change others into disfigured creatures. One girl for example is given some extra arms and eyes from other teens. The story then starts getting a bit metaphysical: some stuff about “living in the angles”, jumping timelines, there’s an ancient evil involved, Lilith is part of it, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Witch Creek Road](https://www.webtoons.com/en/horror/witch-creek-road/episode-1/viewer?title_no=1453&episode_no=1) (warning: NSFW Link)

> Witch Creek Road follows a group of high school seniors who, after taking a wrong turn, find themselves in the midst of a summoning-gone-wrong. At its core, it's survival horror, but it's also a story about love, acceptance, death and revenge. And sexy, flesh-eating demons. Because every story needs sexy, flesh-eating demons.

[image]